# A way to fscanf on only the first line

Tags: c, fgets, scanf

I've been looking into a way to obtain 2 integers, seperated by a space, that are located in the first line of a file that I would read. I considered using

`fscanf(file, "%d %d\n", &wide, &high);`

But that read 2 integers that were anywhere in the file, and would give the wrong output if the first line was in the wrong format. I also tried using

`char line[1001];`
`fgets(line, 1000, file);`

Which seems like the best bet, except for how clumsy it is. It leaves me with a string that has up to a few hundred blank spaces, from which I must extract my precious integers, nevermind checking for errors in formatting.

Surely there is a better option than this? I'll accept any solution, but the most robust solution seems (to me) to be a `fscanf` on the first line only. Any way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can capture the character immediately following the second number in a `char`, and check that the captured character is `'\n'`, like this:

```
int wide, high;
char c;
if (fscanf(file, "%d%d%c", &wide, &high, &c) != 3 || c != '\n') {
    printf("Incorrect file format: expected two ints followed by a newline.");
}
```

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/RtyyD1).

Answer (score 0):

> Which seems like the best bet, except for how clumsy it is.

Nah, it's not clumsy at all (except that you are using the size argument of `fgets()` in the wrong way...). It's perfectly fine & idiomatic. `strtol()` does its job pretty well:

```
char line[LINE_MAX];
fgets(line, sizeof line, file);

char *endp;
int width = strtol(line, &endp, 10);
int height = strtol(endp, NULL, 10);
```